# Why carplay and react native app crashes when click on app icon to open in carplay?

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, simulator, carplay

I am using react-native-carplay(^2.0.0) library for my react native app..

I made the setup as this library suggests and I run my App in different iOS simulators (iPhone 11, 12 in iOS versions 14.4, 14.2, 13.0).. I also tried to run the example that the library provides..

The problem always is that when I open carplay as an external window, I can see the icon of my app but when I click on it, the app close on iOS and carplay simulator without any errors..
Also I saw that "CarPlay.connected" is false even if I can see the app's icon on carplay simulator..

Can anyone help..?
Any ideas are welcome...

Answer (score 0):

I finally run the example of this library using simulator iPhone 11, ios 14.5, xcode 12.5.1